# Definition of an infinite loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Let $E_0$ be a topological space. Are the following two definitions of an infinite loop space $E_0$ equivalent?

**Definition 1:** For each $n>0$, there exists a topological space $E_n$ such that $E_{n-1} = \Omega E_n$. So this is saying $E_0$ is the loop space of the loop space of the loop space of ... etc.

**Definition 2:** For each $n>0$, there exists a topological space $E_n$ such that $E_0 = \Omega^n E_n$.

It's clear that Definition 1 implies Definition 2. For the other way, based on Definition 2, it seems we can only deduce that for each $n>0$, $E_{n-1}$ is homotopic to $\Omega E_n$. So I guess Definition 1 is stronger than Definition 2?

**Edit:**
Every "$=$" above should be interpreted as "is homotopy equivalent to". I also used the phrase "is homotopic to" as a shortcut to "is homotopy equivalent to". I hope this won't cause confusions.

Comment: $E_{n-1}$ "only" homotopic to $\Omega E_n$ wouldn't be a problem to the eyes of a homotopy theorist.  The problem is that definition 2 need not imply this : it's possible that $\Omega X \simeq \Omega Y$ without $X\simeq Y$, or at least it's not obvious why it would be impossible

Comment: The loop space $\Omega X$ only sees the path component of the base point of $X$. So for example, with your definition $2$, you could build something that is really not a spectrum, for example you take $E_0 = *$ is a singleton and the $E_n$ are arbitrary spaces such that the path component of the base point is a singleton. So in particular that you cannot deduce that $E_{n-1}$ is homotopy equivalent (not "homotopic"!) to $\Omega E_n$. -- However I don't know if it's possible to find a counterexample for a space that satisfies Def 2 but not Def 1.

Comment: @Max You are right. But I guess this is impossible if we only consider connected spaces.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for pointing out the issue of connectedness. Then it seems impossible to deduce Def 1 from Def 2. Is there a "universal" definition for infinite loop spaces?

Comment: The correct definition is definitely the first. There is probably a counterexample but I'm still looking for it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Definition 2 may be my misinterpretation of the definition "an infinite loop space is an $n$-fold loop space for all $n$" from a recent seminar talk.

Comment: Ah, but this sentence is not a definition, it's a proposition. "If $X$ is an infinite loop space, then $X$ is an $n$-fold loop space for all $n$."